# Find and replace a certain position with a list of values

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have a file with this kind of record

```
DL2016-12-02P123456             PW5038               1234561180118       123456O00400010180421          0755480            HEALTH            B   NOT APPLICABLE                                    NOT APPLICABLE     2016-08-012016-12-022016-09-012016-08-312016-09-302016-09-012016-09-30949569014            PW5018             07554800010001089200001       00100010892                   00000010304MDIRECT    00000000000000000000{          HPS                           PW5018COCOAA007708200000010304DXQ7262016001
```

I want to format the value present in the field 385-396 and 415-427 in every row. e.g `00000010304M 000000000000{`
After using this command `cut -c 385-396,415-427 --output-delimiter=" "` file. That will return `00000010304M 000000000000{`
According to a reference guide `M = -1` , `{ = +2` , `N = +3` and so on.
As you can see that the data in 396 position is `M` and data in 427 is `{` then the data should look like `-0000001030.41` and `+00000000000.05`. Here M is replaced with -1 where - sign is placed at the start and 1 at M place. Also a decimal is placed before 2 place.

```
Last Character in Input Field|Positive or Negative|Last Number|Incoming Field|Value after replacement
{   +   0   12345{  1234.5
A   +   1   12345A  1234.51
B   +   2   12345B  1234.52
C   +   3   12345C  1234.53
D   +   4   12345D  1234.54
E   +   5   12345E  1234.55
F   +   6   12345F  1234.56
G   +   7   12345G  1234.57
H   +   8   12345H  1234.58
I   +   9   12345I  1234.59

}   -   0   12345}  -1234.5
J   -   1   12345J  -1234.51
K   -   2   12345K  -1234.52
L   -   3   12345L  -1234.53
M   -   4   12345M  -1234.54
N   -   5   12345N  -1234.55
O   -   6   12345O  -1234.56
P   -   7   12345P  -1234.57
Q   -   8   12345Q  -1234.58
R   -   9   12345R  -1234.59
```

This file is just saying that if the field number 396 has M then use the next column data and replace it in current file. means 00000010304M changes to -0000001030.44 . you can see that reference file shows it as M - 4 12345M -1234.54 . E.g M letter to be replaced, changes to 4 with a - sign in front which looks like -1234.54 now in place of 12345M

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please see the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for help on formatting your posts. That said, it looks like you're expecting us to write the whole script for you. We're not a free script-writing service. Start doing it on your own and then ask here if you are having problems with a *specific* part of the process. We won't just do your work for you, but we'll be happy to help *you* do it.

Comment: I have already tried doing it. I am not able to replace content or i think i am not taking a right approach. I am asking for help so that i can get directions as well as knowledge to do it.

Comment: In that case, please explain what you are trying to do more clearly. I don't understand the relationship between your input and output files. Maybe you can give a simpler example. We don't know what the start and end positions are. We don't know how the data should be replaced. Most importantly, asking for a whole script is off topic here. Break it down into smaller problems and ask about each of them, perhaps.

Comment: I don't think it should be on hold as i wanted to give a broad picture of the task i am trying to do.

Comment: I am not asking for whole code. I am trying to know i have to cut the fields and then do the task or is there some way that the substitution can be done in the original file and then i can cut the fields and add.

Comment: Cut what fields? Substitute with what? Please [edit] and clarify. Preferably by giving a much simpler example. Your question will be placed in the reopen queue if you edit but you'll need to explain what you need more clearly.

Comment: Hi @AbhishekGarg. Try posting your attempt at code. That might help to clarify things. And as terdon says, if the problem can be reduced to something simpler, that would help.

Comment: Can you please remove hold from it now and help me with it.Thanks

Comment: I tried to reformat it to make it more clear, but in doing so I see that you left a comment "and some more" -- either remove that, or spell out every replacement that you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that's much clearer! Now, assuming you are running Linux, this command will extract the relevant part of your file: `cut -c 385-396,415-427 --output-delimiter=" " file`. That will return `00000010304M 000000000000{`. If you integrate that into your question, we can focus on the 2nd part, the replacement. So, please [edit] again, use the `cut` command I gave you and give us the whole list of replacements you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot terdon. i have made the changes and now i am just looking for a way to do the replacement according to my reference guide.

Comment: OK, but for that we'll need to see an example of your reference guide. The details will depend on the exact format in that file.

Comment: I have added the file content. It is replacement of last character with the corresponding number along with sign of addition or subtraction.Later all of this data will be used to find out final total

Comment: Please use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) as I asked in my first comment. And please [edit] and explain what that file you added is. What's the source and what is the replacement? Is the file space separated? Tab separated?

Comment: This file is just saying that if the field number 396 has M then use the next column data and replace it in current file. means 00000010304M changes to -0000001030.44 . you can see that reference file shows it as `M   -   4   12345M  -1234.54` . E.g M letter to be replaced, changes to 4 with a - sign in front which looks like -1234.54 now in place of 12345M

Comment: OK, but you need to say all that *in the question*. Comments are easy to miss and can be deleted without warning. All necessary details must be in the question itself.

Comment: I have added the expected data in the question itself. Can you please help me now?

Comment: --output-delimiter doesn't work with -c.

Answer (score 0):

You could continue as you started with `cut`, but split it up in more parts where needed.  To give you an idea, here is a short snippet that would convert the first section on each line.

```
cut -c 385-394,395,396 | \
while read integral dec suffix
do  case $suffix in
        '{');; # Nothing
        A) last=1;;
        B) last=2;;
        ...
        '}') sign=-;;
        J) sign=- last=1;;
        ...
    esac
    echo $sign$integral.$dec$last
done
```

You get the idea.  Expand the `cut` to include fields for the second number too.

If you want to use a separate file with the translation of the final letters you could use `grep` from that file instead of this inline lookup.

Comment: I tried this but the script is giving some error. also the replacement is not done.

Comment: You need to be more specific than “some errors”.  And if necessary add the precise script you used.  (How you completed the ellipsis, how you extended it to both numbers, etc.  The above was just the first draft.)